# Planar graph $G$ that does not contain any cycle of length $\leq k-1$

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a planar graph that does not contain any cycle of length $\le k-1$ where $3\le k \le |V|$.
>
> Prove the inequality $(k-2)|E|\le k|V|-2k$

My attempt so far. If the graph has has $f$ faces/regions than it follows that $(k-2)f\le2m$ where $m$ denotes the number of edges.

Applying this to the Euler formula: $n+f=m+2$. I don't get the desired inequality.

What am I missing ? Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the inequality $k|F|\leq 2|E|$. Then
$$|E|=|V|+|F|-2\leq |V|+\frac{2|E|}{k}-2\implies (k-2)|E|\le k|V|-2k.$$

Comment: Thx, for some reason I used $k-2$ instead of $k$